# Automatic color correction in AS3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, image-processing

I want to color correct a foreground bitmap image so that it 'fits' with a background bitmap image. I am not sure whether this is possible automatically.

Basically I want the reds in the foreground image to match the reds in background image (and the greens and blues too).

My first attempt is measuring the mean values of the red, green and blue channels of the background image and then using the ColorTransform to transform the foreground image using the multiplier parameters so that the ratios between the reds:greens and reds:blues were the same in both images. I also try do some luma correction using the offset parameters so that the foreground and background luma's match  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space#Lightness)

The results are not that bad, but I think they could be better. For example, if there aren't any reds in the background image, but there are some in the foreground image, the foregorund image ends up too blue/green. Maybe this problem is in principle unsolvable...

My question is: are their any 'standard' algorithms to do what I want, and if yes, how should one implement these in AS3?

Edit: tried to clarify my question

Comment: question is a bit vague - what is the exact programming problem you need help with?

Comment: could you mimic the expected behavior with an image software and post it here?

Comment: You should look into [PixelBender](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/pixel_bender_basics.html). It was purpose-built for quick image manipulations. You'll have to learn how to use PixelBender (and its language), but it is definitely the way to go for image processing in Flash.